# Can't disconnect relation of explicit many-to-many

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, prisma

I'm trying to delete some users which are related to a group.

Here is the schema:

```
model User {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  username String 
  email String @unique
  password String?

  group GroupUser[]

}

model Group {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  name String

  user GroupUser[]

}
        
model GroupUser{
  userId String
  user User @relation(fields: [userId],references: [id],onDelete: Cascade,onUpdate:Cascade)

  groupId String
  group Group @relation(fields: [groupId],references: [id],onDelete: Cascade,onUpdate: Cascade)

  @@id([userId,groupId])
}
```

The code to delete the users:

```
async deleteUsersFromGroup(id: string, userData: UpdateGroupDto): Promise<number> {
  const deletedUsers = await prisma.group.update({
  where: {
    id: id,
  },
  data: {
    user: { disconnect: /* trying to put the array of users id here */ },
  },
});
return deletedUsers.length;
```

}

The problem is that I want to give the userID inside of the disconnect but it is asking me for userId_groupId which is the relational key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to delete multiple users at the same time I used the map function inside userId, resorting to prisma.groupUser.delete().

```js
async deleteUsersFromGroup(id: string, userData: DeleteGroupDto): Promise<any> {
       
    
        const response = await prisma.groupUser.deleteMany({
          where: {
            groupId: id,
            userId: { in: userData.users.map(user => user.userId) },
          },
        });
    
        return response.count
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to delete the record from the connecting table i.e. `GroupUser`.

You can try something like this:

```js
await prisma.groupuser.delete({
    where: {
        userId_groupId: {
          userId: 'userId',
          groupId:'groupId'
        }
      }
});
```

If the connecting records are deleted then both the entities would be disconnected.

Comment: It worked for a single user, but I found a way to delete multiple which was what I wanted